# Merging db/migration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a good way to merge rails db migration files into 1 file per table besides splitting **schema.rb** manually?

Most of my migration file was created during development and does not represent real data changes. For historical reasons those files will be still accessible on source control system. I feel uncomfortable keeping those unnecessary files.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Don't bother. The old migration files are not doing any harm, and they may make maintenance easier. Leave them as they are.

Comment: They do make maintenance easier only if migrations represent real data changes, and that's not the case.

Comment: Migration files should represent *schema* changes, not data changes as such. Can you post a sample migration that you'd like to get rid of?

Comment: Dropping numerous columns as not relevant, get ridding of unnecessary indexes, columns renames and such.

Comment: Yeah, those are schema changes. Leave them.

Comment: I've worked on a project that had hundreds and hundreds of migrations. Became cumbersome for new developers.  Was handy to merge years of history into a reasonable starting point

Comment: @AthirNuaimi I’ve worked on projects with hundreds of migrations too. What’s cumbersome about them? Generally you don’t need to touch the old ones at all.

Answer (score 13):

Well, i can imagine that you want to have a clean start. While being in project development mode for your first version release you don't want all the separate migration files. Although they can't hurt obviously.

Basically what you can do, is this.

**FIRST BACKUP your schema and data.**

The db/schema.rb contains (or should contain) the latest version of your schema. Otherwise run:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Now you can clean your migration folder.

Then run:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:schema:load
```

The last command runs the db/schema.rb and create a new schema. This should bring you to the last version of your database.

show db task

> rake -T db

Comment: rake says "Don't know how to build task 'schema:drop'". I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.9

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Squasher](https://github.com/jalkoby/squasher) gem to merge the migrations all olds into one.